# Какой плагин подойдет для отрисовки диаграмы бублика?

Tags: вёрстка, поиск-библиотек

Добрый есть такая диаграма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру тут диаграмма состоит из 5 вариантов, а может из разного количество( Динамически выводится на php )
Можете пожалуйста посоветовать библиотеку для отрисовки, где я бы мог выводить опреленое количество вариантов указав %, а диаграмма отрисует?

Comment: из php прокидывайте данные в js и выводите в удобном виде с помощью charts.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть отличная библиотека [Chart js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html) для JS. При помощи PHP отправляете данные на вью, а там уже с помощью библиотеки отрисовываете.